# Add number rank in front of basic ruby loop so that each result has a number in front of it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops

Very basic question on adding a number rank in front of results for a ruby loop.

```
@model.each do |foo|
#code here to put the number of the element in the loop starting at 1 and going up.  
puts foo.title
  end
```

Which would ideally print the following results.

```
1 titlea
2 titleb
3 titlec
```

haven't been able to find this anywhere - any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depends on what `@model` is. If it's an `Enumerable`, you could do:

```
@model.each_with_index do |foo, i|
  puts "#{i} #{foo.title}"
end
```